# ¿Cuántos tipos existen para preguntas "bloqueadas"?

Tags: soporte, preguntas, pregunta-bloqueada, publicación-bloqueada

Por ejemplo esta pregunta ha sido bloqueada:

- [¿ Es posible saber cuando rotas el móvil en Unity?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/65300/es-posible-saber-cuando-rotas-el-m%C3%B3vil-en-unity)

Alegando: Esta pregunta existe porque tiene importancia histórica,...

lo que implica que no se pueda votar ni en la pregunta ni en la respuesta.

---

He visto este otro tipo en SO:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list#

Alegando: This question's answers are a collaborative...

lo que implica que se pueda votar en la respuesta pero no en pregunta y he visto que la respuesta es wiki.

---

Me pregunto qué otras existen, teniendo en cuenta:

- por ejemplo, en cuáles se puede editar estando bloqueadas, etc.
- por ejemplo, alguna que no se pueda votar en la pregunta, pero sí en la respuesta aunque esta no sea wiki.

*Sí, personalmente estoy interesado en algo similar*

Answer (score 1):

Existen dos tipos de bloqueos:

- [Publicación bloqueada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1994/227)
- [Bloqueo histórico](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1996/227)

---

La pregunta en cuestión que mencionas obtuvo múltiples respuestas. Sucede que necesitas tener por lo menos 10k de reputación en SOen para revisarlas. Lo que hizo el moderador en su momento fue:

- Publicar una respuesta en modo wiki donde se unifican todas las respuestas en una sola
- **Eliminar las demás respuestas**
- Activar el bloqueo más adecuado.

Aquí unos screenshots de dicha pregunta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo que la situación de la pregunta de SOen que mencionas no es un caso similar al de la pregunta en cuestión.

Comment: Gracias por tomase el tiempo sobre todo por las capturas, pero yo se que son este tipo de "bloqueadas", pero me pregunto y mi pregunta, trata sobre saber si existen otro tipo de "bloqueadas" aparte de las mencionadas y cuales son sus caracteristicas.

Comment: @AngelAngel a eso voy. No seas impaciente ;) Solo digo que te noto algo ansioso por este tema. Y por favor, al menos cuando comentes para hablarme, omite ese "Saludos" al final.

Comment: **Primero** no soy impaciente con esta respuesta/s quizas de ser impaciente lo soy en general. **Segundo** pienso que esta respuesta no responde a mi pregunta -> **Me pregunto que otras existen de existir:** esta ya la cito, pero no estaria de mas en una respuesta siempre y cuando se añadan las que no conozco y si no existen mas pues que se aclare. **Tercero** si no interpreto bien mi pregunta ser humilde y aceptar que lo que respondio no es lo correcto, y no venirme como debo despedirme o si tengo o no que decir *Saludos* yo no se que tiene usted con migo y la verdad ni me importa. Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel qué mal que te impacientes y te enojes. Nuevamente, tranquilo que ya estoy por responder lo que pides. Considera que, como cualquier usuario de la comunidad, uso parte de mi tiempo para responder las preguntas. Y menciono lo que indicas porque luce como si quisieras un caso similar. Reitero omitir ese "Saludos".

Comment: @AngelAngel respuesta actualizada. Una vez más, omitir ese "Saludos"

Comment: Como quiere tener la razon, le repito no me impaciento simplemente veo el comentario y comento, "aunque" quizas usted no esta acostumbrado a respetar a los demas yo si, y si alguien me comenta yo intento responderle lo mas rapido que puedo, enojarme dice, por que deberia de enojarme por algo tan insignificante. *...menciono lo que indicas porque luce como si quisieras un caso similar* claramente dejo en mi pregunta que me interesan las alternativas y mas en esta direccion, me pregunto **ahora** si ha leido bien mi pregunta, sobre lo del saludo lo siento pero va ser que no. Saludos

Comment: P.D: tomese su tiempo no tengo prisas, pero para otra vez quizas le convenga poner la respuesta oculta hasta que la tenga entera, o redactarla en un fichero de texto y publicarla entera, se lo digo por si le comentan nada mas terminar de publicarla no piense que la gente es impaciente, quizas sean educados. Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel puedes revisar más información en [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites). Solo exhibo lo indicado allí. Y muestro también el caso puntual de lo que mencionas. Si tu pregunta apunta a conocer los tipos específicos de bloqueo, mi respuesta será: "si no está en Meta SE, no lo pondría aquí".

Comment: @AngelAngel sin "Saludos" para la próxima ;)