# ¿Qué es una publicación bloqueada?

Tags: soporte, faq, publicación-bloqueada

Una publicación puede ser *bloqueada*.

- ¿Qué significa "bloquear" una publicación?
- ¿Quién puede bloquear una publicación?
- ¿Cuándo debería bloquearse una publicación?

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378)

---

Adaptado de: [What is a “locked” post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22228/182862)

Answer (score 6):

### ¿Qué significa "bloquear" una publicación?

Una pregunta o respuesta que está bloqueada ya no puede aceptar:

- ediciones
- votos a favor ni en contra
- comentarios ni voto a comentarios
- nuevas respuestas *<sup>(solo para preguntas)</sup>*
- votos de cierre, votos de reapertura *<sup>(solo para preguntas)</sup>*

En el caso de preguntas bloqueadas, las respuestas (desbloqueadas) no están asociadas a estas restricciones.

Las publicaciones bloqueadas pueden ser desbloqueadas luego por los moderadores o ser configuradas para [ser bloqueadas temporalmente](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106137/better-handling-of-locked-questions-and-answers/106143#106143). Los periodos comunes para el bloqueo son de 1 hora, 24 horas o 1 semana.

### ¿Quién puede *bloquear* una publicación?

Solo los moderadores con diamante puedes bloquear o desbloquear las publicaciones.

### ¿Cuándo debería *bloquearse* una publicación?

Las publicaciones deberían ser bloqueadas generalmente solo en los casos donde sucede algo *realmente malo*. En particular, donde las ediciones y actualizaciones consecuentes son activamente perjudiciales para el sistema.

Algunos ejemplos de cuándos podría bloquearse una publicación incluyen:

- Una pregunta o respuesta donde hay votos y ediciones repetidos de manera que parece un juego, hack, o un abuso del sistema.
- Una pregunta que se abre y cierra repetidas veces sin alcanzar el concenso de la comunidad de si debe permanecer abierta o cerrada.
- Una pregunta que, por cualquier razón, continúa atrayendo publicaciones difamatorias, spam u otras respuestas inapropiadas.
- Una pregunta que es vandalizada repetidamente por el autor de la pregunta; por ejemplo, al modificar drásticamente el significado de la pregunta que invalide las respuestas actualies, o para destruir/oscurecer la pregunta.

Otro tipo de publicación bloqueada es una pregunta unida. Cuando un moderador une dos preguntas que son duplicados exactos, todas las respuestas se mueven a una pregunta y la otra pregunta se deja como un "resguardo", sin respuestas. La pregunta de resguardo está bloqueada.

### ¿Qué hacer si estoy en desacuerdo con el *bloqueo* aplicado a una publicación?

Si tienes una razón *justificable* para desbloquear una publicación, deberías reportarlo para que reciba la atención de un moderador usando el enlace "reportar" debajo de la publicación. Selecciona el motivo "otro" y provee una explicación detallada de tu idea en la caja de texto.

Un moderator revisará tu reporte, y si está de acuerdo con tus argumentos, desbloqueará la publicación.

Considera que lo mencionado anteriormente no aplica para las publicaciones que están bloqueadas debido a su significado histórico, en los cuales no existe la opción para reportar.

---

Adaptado de [What is a “locked” post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22229/182862)