# ¿Qué es un bloqueo de importancia histórica y para qué se usa?

Tags: soporte, faq, herramientas-moderación

Los bloqueos históricos se aplican algunas veces a las preguntas.

- ¿Qué es un bloqueo de importancia histórica?
- ¿Cuál es el propósito de un bloqueo de importancia histórica?
- ¿Cómo se ven afectadas las preguntas por el bloqueo de importancia histórica?
- ¿Cuándo es apropiado bloquear una pregunta por razones históricas? ¿Cuándo no es apropiado?
- ¿Cómo solicito el bloqueo de importancia histórica para una pregunta?

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378)

---

Adaptado de [What is a historical lock, and what is it used for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126587/182862)

Answer (score 6):

#### ¿Qué es un Bloqueo de Importancia Histórica?

Un bloqueo de importancia histórica es un mecanismo por el cual los moderadores pueden marcar las publicaciones como artefactos históricos. Las preguntas que son bloqueadas por importancia histórica presentan la siguiente noticia en la publicación:

> ### bloqueada por Moderador♦ Mar 16 a las 20:01
>
> Esta pregunta existe porque tiene importancia histórica, pero **no se la considera una buena pregunta relacionada con el tema en cuestión para este sitio**, así que no la utilices como evidencia de que puedes formular preguntas similares aquí. Esta pregunta y sus respuestas están congeladas y no se pueden modificar. Más información: [ayuda].

#### ¿Cuál es el propósito de un Bloqueo de Importancia Histórica?

Un bloqueo de importancia histórica preserva el contenido antiguo que fue muy popular cuando se publicó originalmente, pero ahora está fuera del alcance del sitio donde está publicado. Bloquear una pregunta por importancia histórica finaliza el debate respecto a si una pregunta debería ser mantenida en el sitio o eliminarse, y es usualmente el estado final de una pregunta que ha sido eliminada y recuperada más de una vez.

#### ¿Cómo se ven afectadas las preguntas por Bloqueo de Importancia Histórica?

En adición a la nota de publicación que se muestra prominentemente, las publicaciones que son bloqueadas por importancia histórica son "congeladas en el tiempo": no pueden recibir votos, ser reportadas, respondidas, editadas o comentadas (aunque los moderadores ♦ todavía pueden hacer todo esto). Las preguntas bloqueadas por importancia histórica se omiten de las listas de preguntas normales (esas que aparecen en la página de inicio, /questions y las otras listas por etiquetas), pero todavía pueden ser encontradas al buscar las palabras de la publicación o del título (mediante la búsqueda en el sitio o Google, etc). Se modifica la apariencia visual de la publicación por completo tras remover las flechas de votos de la pregunta y las respuestas.

Cabe notas que las preguntas bloqueadas por importancia histórica en los sitios meta no se ocultan de esta forma, aunque sus preguntas y respuestas están congeladas de la misma manera.

#### ¿Cuándo es apropiado bloquear una pregunta por razones históricas?

Las preguntas pueden ser bloqueadas por importancia histórica cuando:

1. La publicación está Fuera del Alcance del sitio o No Es Constructiva, y
2. La publicación es estelar, a pesar de su naturaleza fuera de tema, y
3. Existe un gran número de vistas, votos a favor y enlaces a la publicación, y
4. La publicación es contenciosa; por ejemplo, se ha cerrado y reabierto al menos una vez, o eliminado y recuperado al menos una vez.

#### ¿Cuándo no es apropiado bloquear una pregunta por importancia histórica?

Las preguntas no deberían ser bloqueadas por importancia histórica si:

1. Se mantienen activamente, o
2. Tienen poco o ningún valor rescatable.

Una buena regla de pulgar hacia arriba: Si la pregunta no cumple con la tercera regla de Jeff Atwood publicada en la entrada de blog ["We Hate Fun Here"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/), probablemente no sea un buen candidato para el bloqueo por importancia histórica. La tercera regla es:

> ¿Esta pregunta me enseña algo que podría mejorar mi trabajo? ¿Puedo aprender algo de ella?

#### ¿Cómo solicito el bloqueo de importancia histórica para una pregunta?

Reporta la pregunta para atención de un moderador, con la opción "se necesita la intervención de un moderador". En la descripción del reporte, explica por qué piensas que la publicación debería ser bloqueada por importancia histórica. Un moderador evaluaraá la pregunta usando los criterios mencionados previamente, y bloqueará la pregunta o declinará tu reporte con una explicación.

Alternativamente, si quieres intentar y ganar un mayor soporte de la comunidad para la pregunta, o contestar a la decisión del moderador, puedes publicar una pregunta aquí en Meta.