# ¿Qué hacer con Definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio?

Tags: discusión, meta, temática

En diciembre del 2015 se publicó [Definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/161/65). En aquel entonces estábamos en la beta privada y por salir a la beta pública, pero hoy ya nos encontramos con un sitio graduado y con los primeros moderadores de la comunidad electos.

Ese hilo cuenta con 13 respuestas proponiendo temas y etiquetas algunos aún y cuando tenían votos positivos las etiquetas sugeridas no tienen preguntas, como es el caso de

- [arquitectura-de-software](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arquitectura-de-software)
- [diseño-orientado-a-objetos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dise%c3%b1o-orientado-a-objetos)
- [dba](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dba) / [administracion-bbdd](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/administracion-bbdd)

Otras tienen sólo una pregunta, la cual podría ser eliminada automáticamente, tales como

- [historia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/historia)

En el caso particular de las tareas escolares, tiene votos negativos, pero en la ayuda oficial se mencionan lineamientos para ese tipo de preguntas. Supongo que los votos negativos se deben al uso de etiqueta `tarea-escolar` `tarea-para-el-hogar` porque como etiquetas son malas así como son malas las etiquetas `principiante`, `avanzado` etc.

¿Debemos seguir agregando respuestas, votando en la pregunta referida o debería "bloquearse por valor histórico" y abrir una o varias discusiones al respecto?

**Relacionado**

- [¿Cómo deberíamos gestionar las propuestas en Meta para que sus respuestas/encuestas tengan efecto?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2093/65)
- [¿Qué es un bloqueo de importancia histórica y para qué se usa?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1996/65)

Comment: Osea basicamente preguntas si abrimos otro o no?

Comment: @jasilva Pues espero una respuesta más amplia que un simple sí o no

Comment: Bien reflotado el tema, Rubén. Por lo que entiendo, ¿será cuestión de ir lanzando cada uno de los temas en preguntas distintas?

Comment: @fedorqui: No lo sé aún. Al momento hay dos respuestas con igual puntuación, 2. En [la respuesta "naranja"](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2635/65) se propone eso.  En [la respuesta "morada"](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2633/65) se propone inicialmente que se le de valor oficial al hilo en cuestión.  Como hay varios de los asiduos que continúan de vacaciones o con mucho trabajo no daría ninguna como la respuesta que refleja lo que quiere la comunidad. Nota: Uso colores para no personalizar y pues espero que los colores usados no sesguen la opinión, cosa que parece imposible :D

Answer (score 1):

Yo creo que debemos darle **valor oficial**. Que no quede ninguna duda de que la temática del sitio es la que ahí se define.
Y si no ahí pues en otro sitio. Pero mejor ahí que ya hay camino recorrido, ¿para qué empezar de nuevo?

Y para hacerlo oficial sería conveniente una edición de los moderadores en la pregunta afirmando que ese hilo define la temática del sitio. Y definir unas reglas para saber cuándo una propuesta pasa a formar parte de la temática del sitio. Por ejemplo: Tener un total de +10 y el doble de positivos que de negativos. Una vez una propuesta nueva pasa a formar parte de la temática hacer una discusión en meta anunciándolo y marcarla como destacada durante por ejemplo un mes para que lo vea todo el mundo. Aunque antes de esto habría que dejar la etiqueta correspondiente bien redactada.  Dado que ya hay varias que cumplirían esos requisitos yo iría anunciando una a una cada mes aunque todas entrasen en vigor inmediatamente.

Naturalmente lo que propongo es una primera aproximación, un borrador. Invito a mejorarlo.

Comment: Alternativamente, si no se quiere que ese hilo defina la temática, editarlo y dejarlo claro. Sea lo que sea que quede claro y evitemos situaciones en que unos cierran por estar fuera del ámbito y otros protestamos haciendo referencia a ese hilo.

Answer (score 1):

## Respuesta corta

El hilo debería cerrarse y manejar la discusión de la temática usando una pregunta por cada tema con las etiquetas [temática](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tem%c3%a1tica) y las que se vuelvan oficiales incluir la etiqueta [faq](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq) o alguna otra similar en el sentido que sólo pueda se agregado por un moderador de la comunidad.

Así mismo, el artículo [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoveflow.com/help/on-topic) debería incluir un enlace al [FAQ para sitios de Stack Exchange](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/65)

## Explicación

Algunos temas es muy claro que la comunidad está de acuerdo en incluir como es el de [revisión-de-código](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revisi%c3%b3n-de-c%c3%b3digo) sin embargo otros temas no han recibido la atención adecuada pues si bien tienen votos positivos, ha faltado "sembrar" las etiquetas con preguntas que sirvan de ejemplo. Por otro lado, algunos temas no son del todo claro cuál es la opinión de la comunidad, y los comentarios no son del todo útiles para argumentar por la limitación de formato y extensión, además de que su propósito es el de solicitar aclarar o dar sugerencias de cómo mejorar una publicación.

Además, la opinión más importante es la de los miembros asiduos que continúan activos, aunque se tomen "vacaciones" de vez en cuando.

### Antecendentes

El [comentario](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/161/definici%C3%B3n-de-la-tem%C3%A1tica-apropiada-para-el-sitio#comment726_161) de Flimsy a [Definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/161/65)

> Eso es la mejor forma de decidir para cada sitio? Creo que puede ser mejor una pregunta por cada sitio... Porque a veces (tal vez la mayoría), no es un simple pregunta de "si o no". Por ejemplo, creo que hay muchas preguntas de Programmers que pueden ser dentro de la temática aquí (licensias de software, algoritmos, etc), y otras temas no (como trabajar con otro programador arrogante). Igual con ServerFault y SuperUser. Unos clases pueden funcionar aquí, y otros no.

Comment: Poco me importa que se haga de una manera u otra mientras se haga. Por lo que me sumo a esta propuesta y en cuanto tenga más votos que la que escribí yo pues borro esa otra.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo en que debe hacerse algo. Lo que no me convence es mezclar la temática y las etiquetas, aunque en muchos casos van de la mano no siempre es así, valga el ejemplo de las tareas escolares: seguramente no deba haber una etiqueta para eso pero una pregunta bien planteada es válida venga de donde venga, ya sea un problema del trabajo, algo personal o un ejercicio de clase; lo que no se puede permitir es poner el enunciado de un ejercicio y que otro lo resuelva. Volviendo al tema ,me parece bien esta propuesta para quitar ruido y resetear aprovechando que nos acabamos de graduar

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos: Te pido que **no** la vayas a borrar ya que mencionas varias cosas que es importante considerar e inclusive incorporar en lo que vaya a quedar como acuerdo de la comunidad.

Comment: @Rubén Sugiero que incorpores a la respuesta que has escrito lo que veas necesario. Mejor no dividir. Y hasta que lo hagas me espero.