# ¿Qué hacer con la etiqueta arquitectura?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, desambiguación-etiquetas, reetiquetado

El wiki de [arquitectura](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arquitectura) habla sobre arquitectura de hardware pero las preguntas que usan esa etiqueta se refieren a [arquitectura-de-software](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arquitectura-de-software).

Este última recién la creé para reemplazar la primera en un par de preguntas. Antes de proceder con el reetiquetado de más preguntas me gustaría conocer la opinión de la comunidad al respecto.

En [respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/163/65) a [Definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/161/65) se propone [arquitectura-de-software](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arquitectura-de-software) como dentro de la temática del sitio y tiene una puntuación de 27 (+28/-1)

En [respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/162/65) también como respuesta a [Definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/161/65) se proponen temas sobre hardware. Tiene una puntuación de -18 (+3/-21).

**Relacionado**

- [¿Qué hacer con Definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2627/65)

Answer (score 5):

El tag [arquitectura](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arquitectura) es demasiado amplio y en este caso ambiguo.

El nuevo tag: [arquiectura-de-software](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arquiectura-de-software) me parece excelente.

En cuanto a [arquitectura-de-hardware](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arquitectura-de-hardware) solo me parece que hay 1 pregunta: [Compatibilidad entre versiones y arquitectura en Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/58200/compatibilidad-entre-versiones-y-arquitectura-en-java) por lo cual creo que por ahora **no** es necesario crearla.