# ¿Las preguntas sin responder afectan en algo al sitio?

Tags: discusión

He visto varias preguntas (tambien me ha pasado a mi) en las cuales se empieza a pedir más detalles por medio de los comentarios y "sin querer queriendo" se llega a la solucion con el OP. Considero que esto no esta del todo mal, ya que se aprovecha que el OP este en linea y disponible para ampliar el problema y resolverlo. No se si sea por pereza o por que lo olvidamos, pero a veces no se publica una respuesta como tal y la pregunta se queda sin su respuesta, aunque el OP si solucionó su problema.

Revisando la pestaña de Preguntas sin Responder, me di cuenta de que hay varias preguntas asi y la verdad no tengo nada contra esto. Mi pregunta es por pura curiosidad. ¿La métrica de preguntas sin responder (sin respuesta y sin respuesta aceptada) afecta en algo el sitio? Es decir, si llegamos a cierto porcentaje, ¿el equipo de SE haría algo? ¿Esto nos da algún tipo de mala imagen en alguna forma?

Si fuera el caso que si nos afecta, ¿cuál sería la mejor forma de atacar el problema?

Comment: La verdad que desconozco si afecta de alguna manera aunque supongo que en las estadísticas nunca queda bien "Ha habido un 35% de preguntas sin responder" p.ej. Independientemente de eso, cuando este tipo de sucesos ocurren, suelo decirle al OP que por favor publique la respuesta o, en caso de que haya sido a través de un chat y le he estado ayudando (o por comentarios) y si veo que el OP no responde a la pregunta, entonces publico la solución como respuesta por si a algún otro le puede servir.

Answer (score 2):

Una métrica es útil en la medida que se use para determinar hacer o no algo. En el proceso de graduación es una media teóricamente importante ya que tiene una meta, pero Stack Overflow en español se graduó incluso sin alcanzar la meta de pregunta respondidas.

Hoy día, en el día a día, me parece que la métrica por sí sola **no afecta en nada** porque no creo que alguien se detenga a ver esa métrica **para saber si toma al sitio como uno útil e interesante** pero en términos de revisiones periódicas podría ser útil en conjunto con otras métricas para determinar si se deben orientar la promoción del uso del sitio hacia algún público en particular o bien en las discusiones acerca de la temática del mismo como:

[¿Qué hacer con Definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2627/65)

Comment: Quizá sería interesante agregar a tu respuesta que es importante no utilizar los comentarios para responder preguntas, si no para realizar aclaraciones. Los comentarios son susceptibles de ser eliminados, con lo que la pregunta quedaría sin respuesta. Si hemos llegado a una solución via comentarios, se debe añadir la respuesta posteriormente.