# ¿Qué hacer cuando me encuentro una solución en comentarios y el OP responde su propia pregunta pero no la marca como aceptada?

Tags: discusión, comentarios, respuesta

De pronto mi título no me hace entender muy bien, pero quiero saber qué hacer en los siguientes casos.

1. ¿Que pasa cuando se da la solución a una pregunta por medio de los comentarios?¿Es necesario copiar esa solución como una respuesta?
2. ¿Que hacer cuando el usuario que pregunta soluciona su problema con una respuesta pero no la marca como aceptada?

Comment: Me parecen que tus preguntas son totalmente validas y como tales merecen una respuesta correcta (que ya publique). Pero me da curiosidad: ¿en que te afectan estas situaciones? ¿Has tenido algun problema por alguna de estas situaciones?

Comment: No nunca he tenido problemas, solo he notado en varias preguntas ambos casos, y aveces me cuesta encontrar una solución optima entre tantas respuestas o comentarios, personalmente siempre intento llegar directamente a la pregunta que tiene el chulito verde jejeje y gracias por tu respuesta !

Comment: Camilo: La pregunta es demasiado amplia porque incluyes dos preguntas en una. Lo mejor es publicar cada pregunta por separado.

Comment: Rubén, muchas gracias por tus respuestas y tu comentario, hice la pregunta así por que he notado que varias preguntas tenían numerales con pequeñas dudas, muchas gracias por la aclaración.

Comment: Camilo: No hay de que :) Por cierto, para enviar una notificación a alguien que ha dejado un comentario, usa @ como prefijo. Mas detalles en [¿Cómo funcionan las @respuestas en los comentarios](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1357/65).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. **No, no es necesario.** Al parecer, [las preguntas sin contestar no afectan en nada al sitio.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2763/las-preguntas-sin-responder-afectan-en-algo-al-sitio) Asi que, lo que yo hago es alentar al que respondió a que ponga una respuesta, **pero no lo presiono demasiado**, ya que todos aqui actuamos voluntariamente. Se publica una respuesta con el objetivo primario de resolver la duda y el objetivo secundario de que otras personas puedan verla y beneficiarse de ella.
2. **No hay que hacer nada.** Segun el centro de ayuda, en el articulo [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) dice:

> Como el autor de la pregunta, tendrás una opción adicional: aceptar la
>   respuesta que pienses que es la mejor solución a tu problema.
>
> (...)
>
> El aceptar una respuesta no es obligatorio; no te sientas
>   presionado a aceptar la primera respuesta que recibas. Espera hasta
>   que recibas la respuesta que conteste tu pregunta de la mejor manera.

Es decir, que únicamente el autor tiene la posibilidad de marcarla como aceptada. Si el no lo hace, no hay forma de forzarlo a que lo haga y esto no afecta en nada al sitio.

Comment: "hay que"... hmmm... Nada es obligatorio... Ni siquiera responder, ni preguntar, ni entrar a SOes... Uno lo hace si tiene ganas... Y si tiene ganas, el formato del sitio es preguntas arriba, respuestas abajo... Si uno tiene ganas, hace todo lo que esté a su alcance para que quede así.

Answer (score 8):

> ¿Que pasa cuando se da la solución a una pregunta por medio de los comentarios?¿Es necesario copiar esa solución como una respuesta?

Lo mejor es publicar las respuestas como respuestas.

La finalidad de los comentarios es dar recomendaciones sobre cómo mejorar las preguntas y respuestas, solicitar agregar información adicional o aclarar la publicación y tienen carácter provisional, es decir, eventualmente deberían ser eliminados.

Si una publicación tienen muchos comentarios, algunos de ellos podrían esconderse, en particular los que tengan menos votos positivos o ninguno.

Preguntas relacionadas:

- [Etiqueta a la hora de copiar una respuesta de los comentarios](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412/65)
- [¿Qué hacer en caso de que el OP publica en comentarios o en la pregunta misma la solución que encontró a su pregunta?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1454/65)

Answer (score 4):

> ¿Que hacer cuando el usuario que pregunta soluciona su problema con una respuesta pero no la marca como aceptada?

No es obligatorio que el autor de la pregunta acepte una respuesta. Si se trata de un usuario nuevo, se le puede dejar un comentario explicándole cómo funciona el sitio. Generalmente yo dejo un enlace a [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien responde mi pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Preguntas relacionadas:

- [Preguntas abandonadas, inclusive que tienen buenas respuestas y/o comentarios](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/822/65)
- [¿Por qué no se implementa un proceso para aceptar respuestas de preguntas abandonadas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/649/65)